# How do I replace all occurrences of "/" in a string with "_" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, replace

For some reason the `"".replace()` method only replaces the first occurrence and not the others. Any ideas?

Answer (score 27):

You have to use the `g` modifier (for global) in your replace call.

```
str = str.replace(/searchString/g, "replaceWith")
```

In your particular case it would be:

```
str = str.replace (/\//g, "_");
```

Note that you must escape the `/` in the regular expression.

Comment: You may also need the "m" option for a multiline string.

Comment: To make it more clear for the given problem: `str = str.replace (/\//g, "_");`

Comment: Once your problem is solved, you should mark it as answered :)

Comment: @illuminatedtiger: No, really. You should mark it as answered.

Answer (score 9):

```
"Your/string".split("/").join("_")
```

if you don't require the power of RegExp

Answer (score 7):

```
str.replace(/\//g,”_”)
```

Comment: Interesting that this answer contains the same Microsoft "smart quotes" as were originally in Mayra's answer.

Comment: saved the day, amigo

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 text = text.replace(new RegExp("textToReplace","g"), "replacemntText"));
```