# JavaScript .replace doesn't replace all occurrences

Tags: javascript, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript multiple replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832257/javascript-multiple-replace)
>   [How do I replace all occurrences of "/" in a string with "_" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159251/how-do-i-replace-all-occurrences-of-in-a-string-with-in-javascript)

In JavaScript, `"11.111.11".replace(".", "")` results in `"11111.11"`. How can that be?

Firebug Screenshot:
[image: Firebug Screenshot]

Comment: old answers, today you probably want [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Quote from [the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> To perform a global search and replace, either include the g switch in
>   the regular expression or if the first parameter is a string, include
>   g in the flags parameter. **Note:**
>   The flags argument does not work in v8 Core (Chrome and Node.js) and will be removed from Firefox.

So it should be:

```
"11.111.11".replace(/\./g, '');
```

---

This version (at the moment of edit) does work in Firefox...

```
"11.111.11".replace('.', '', 'g');
```

... but, as noted at the very MDN page, its support will be dropped soon.

Comment: The "flags" parameter in your first example is non-standard, and won't work in Chrome or IE.

Comment: @jvenema Thank you, updated the answer mentioning that. Actually I never used strings in `.replace` first param when in need of global replace, so was a bit surprised when seeing that it's still possible to do without regex modifiers. )

Comment: Thank you, this works... This is the most unintentional code I've ever come to see in my whole career :D

Comment: It just saved my day... I was wondering what was happening... thanks !

Comment: Firefox behaves like you have already passed /\./g as first parameter and replaces all instances.

Answer (score 9):

With a regular expression and flag `g` you got the expected result

```
"11.111.11".replace(/\./g, "")
```

it's IMPORTANT to use a regular expression because this:

```
"11.111.11".replace('.', '', 'g'); // dont' use it!!
```

[is not standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, replace() is a javascript function, and not a jquery function.

The above code replaces only the first occurrence of "." (not every occurrence). To replace every occurrence of a string in JavaScript, you must provide the replace() method a regular expression with a global modifier as the first parameter, like this:

```
"11.111.11".replace(/\./g,'')
```