# Remove two same string from a string

Tags: javascript, string, replace

```
var string = "user1,user2,user1,user3,user4,user1,";
```

I want to remove all 'user1,' from the string but by 'replace' method I can just remove one of them.

Comment: Please post the code you have.

Comment: duplicate of [JavaScript .replace doesn't replace all occurrences](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12729449/218196)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript multiple replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832257/javascript-multiple-replace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use regexp

```
 var string = "user1,user2,user1,user3,user4,user1,";
 string.replace(/user1/g, '');
```

EDITED CODE

```
    var string = "user1,user2,user1,user3,user4,user1,";
    var find = 'user1';
    var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
    string = string.replace(re, '');
```

Comment: That sounds very well. I'm sorry I can't give you more than 1 point. (THIS IS MY ANSWER.)

Answer (score 2):

try out this..

```
    var string = "user1,user2,user1,user3,user4,user1,";
    string.replace(/user1,/g, '');
    alert('string .. '+string);
```

Comment: `replaceAll` is of jquery's!

Comment: It seems there is no 'replaceAll' method in the javascript library. How can I use it?

Comment: `@Sponge Bob` please find edited answer...

Comment: I'd use `/\buser1,/g` so `"luser1,"` would be left untouched.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/79DgJ/

```
 var str= "user1,user2,user1,user3,user4,user1,";
 str = str.replace(/user1,/g, '');  //replaces all 'user1,'
```

Comment: How can I replace /user1,/ with a variable?

Answer (score 2):

First parameter replace method can be regular expression.
Use option 'g' for replace all matches.

`var string = "user1,user2,user1,user3,user4,user1,";`

`string = string.replace(/user1,/g, '');`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I want to use a variable instead of /user1,/ just like this: string.replace(/users+','/g, '');

Comment: Use:
`var number = 1,
    userRegExp = new RegExp('user' + number, 'g');

string = string.replace(userRegExp, '');`

Answer (score 2):

try this, 
split the string, get the array, filter it to remove duplicate items, join them back.

```
var uniqueList=string.split(',').filter(function(item,i,allItems){
    return i==allItems.indexOf(item);
}).join(',');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5dvbs/)

Comment: Well, that's fine but a little complicated.