# Can't replace() using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace all "w" with "e":

```
var d = document.getElementById('hash').innerHTML.replace("/w/g","e");
```

But it doesn't replace anything! Earlier I tried using replace("w","e"), but it replaced only the first "w".
 So, what to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you actually want to modify the content (`innerHTML`) of an element (*the original version of your question made it very likely*), you should use this:

```
var el = document.getElementById('hash');
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/w/g, 'e');
```

... as `replace` (as any other string method) doesn't change the operated string in place -  instead it creates a new string (result of replacement operation) and returns it.

If you only want to make a new, transformed version of the element's contents, the only change should be using *proper regex* object, written either with regex literal (delimited by `/` symbols) or with `new RegExp(...)` construct. In this particular case the latter would definitely be an overkill. So just drop the quotes around `/w/g` (already done in the code snippet above), and you'll be fine. )

As for '...`.replace('w', 'e')` does replace only once...' part, that's actually quite a common gotcha: when used with a string as the first argument, `.replace()` will do its work [**no more than once**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12729473/1229023).

Comment: Seemed like this is what they wanted, but turns out to be a poorly written question. They've since updated OP to be `var d =`, making it seem like they do in fact want a string.

Comment: I know how replace works. I wrote, that earlier I tried using replace("w","e"), but it REPLACED only the first "w". But I forgot that regex mustn't be put in quotes!

Answer (score 5):

You're giving `replace` a string instead of a regex. Use a *real* regex:

```
var d = document.getElementById('hash').innerHTML.replace(/w/g,"e");
```