# How to replace dashes in a string?

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a string like this:

```
d3f0c3cdf363-4303-8761-8e190f054be3
```

but when I use this code:

```
const currentUserId = masterInfo.user.id.replace('-', '')
console.log('currentUserId', masterInfo.user.id.replace('-', ''))
```

I still get this:

```
currentuserId d3f0c3cdf363-4303-8761-8e190f054be3
```

How can I remove all instances of `-`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should pass a `g` in your Regex:

```
const currentUserId = masterInfo.user.id.replace(new RegExp(/-/, 'gm'), ``)
```

Demo:

```js
const s = "d3f0c3cdf363-4303-8761-8e190f054be3"
const test = s.replace(new RegExp(/-/, 'gm'), ``)

console.log(test)
```

- `g`: **global**: Don't return after first match
- `m`: **multi line**: `^` and `$` match start/end of line

Answer (score 0):

Use `replaceAll` instead of `replace`.

replaceAll replaces all occurrence of char/string and to make replace work add a global flag. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729449/javascript-replace-doesnt-replace-all-occurrences)

```
const currentUserId = masterInfo.user.id.replaceAll('-', '')
console.log('currentUserId', masterInfo.user.id.replaceAll('-', ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution for it. you can run here and check output also.

`replaceAll` is not working with react-native.

```js
const message = 'd3f0c3-cdf363-4303-8761-8e190f054be3';
const result = message.replace(/-/g,'');
console.log(result);
```