# replace does not replace every character in a sentence

Tags: javascript, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does javascript replace only first instance when using replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967119/why-does-javascript-replace-only-first-instance-when-using-replace)
>   [How do I replace all occurrences of “/” in a string with “_” in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159251/how-do-i-replace-all-occurrences-of-in-a-string-with-in-javascript)

I want to replace every `-` in a sentence but it only replace the first `-`. Here is my code:

```
var string = 'this-is-a-line-of-words';
alert(string.replace('-', '/'));​
```

Why does it only replace the first character I want to replace? [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/cdyTS/).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a global regex:

```
string.replace(/-/g, '/')
```

Comment: Many thanks for a fast answer! I'll accept it when I can :)

Answer (score 1):

Please use `string.replace(/-/g, '/')`. And check [this](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-replace) doc please.

Comment: Thanks :) I didn't Googled so well this time because I was desperate and even tired after hard work :/ Sorry